# Is there a way to remove extra source files from a git root node?

Tags: git

I have an orphan root node which has extra files in it that came from the other root node.  Is there a way to remove the extra files in the orphan root node as if they were never there, but not touch the main root node?

Comment: Delete them and `git commit --amend`?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "root nodes"? Like 2 different remotes? Or do you mean branches?

Comment: @wspurgin Same repository, but these two branches don't share the same parent.

Comment: Okay so you have two branches that start from different parents, but still share history right (there is still some ancestor that they share)?

Comment: @wspurgin, they share history unintentionally.  The files in the main branch were never deleted when making the orphan.  I have 3 nodes in the orphan.  The orphan is merged into the main when we get a new release of sources that will be added to the orphan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several important points here that will guide you:

- Commits are identified by their unique hash ID.  Branch names just contain the hash ID of one particular commit, to be treated as the *last* commit on that branch.  Each commit store the hash ID(s) of its parent(s).
- Every commit is a complete snapshot.  That is, commits don't contain *changes*, so there's nothing special about a root commit except that it has no parent(s).
- No part of *any* commit can ever be changed.
- However, any commit can be extracted (unfrozen into the index, and usually on into the work-tree as well).  The extracted, unfrozen commit can be modified and the new index can be used to make a *new* commit, which will of course have a different hash ID.

Hence, if you have:

```
A  <-B  <-C   <-- master1

D  <-E   <-- master2
```

and you dislike the snapshot in commit `D`, you can simply extract commit `D` and make a new commit `F` with no parent so that `F` is a new root commit:

```
$ git checkout master2
$ git checkout --orphan master3
$ git rm ...
$ git commit -m 'make commit F'
```

resulting in:

```
A  <-B  <-C   <-- master1

D  <-E   <-- master2

F   <-- master3
```

Note that you must now copy the effect of commit `E` if you want to replace `master2` with `master3`:

```
$ git cherry-pick master2
```

giving:

```
A  <-B  <-C   <-- master1

D  <-E   <-- master2

F  <-E'  <-- master3
```

You can now delete `master2` and rename `master3` to `master2`.  To anyone not paying attention to hash IDs, looking only at branch names instead, it now *seems* as though you modified commit `D`.  (You didn't, and anyone paying attention to *hash IDs*, as Git does, will know this.)

Comment: Ok, this looks like it will do as I need.  I'll get back to you if I have any other issues with this.

Comment: Turns out, I didn't have extra source files in the branch. *Whew!* I had misunderstood what I was looking at. As this answer looks good, I'll just give you the score  Should have used the command `git show  --name-only <E-hash>` to show me what was actually stored.  Panicked for nothing.